# Navigation component- Custom views states are getting overwritten by last view

Tags: android, navigation, android-custom-view

I am facing weird behavior, where I am using navigation component without use of live data. I have created custom view(compound view) and adding this view wherever needed. For example

```
public class InputCompoundView extends ConstraintLayout {
  private ViewInputTextBinding binding;

  public InputCompoundView(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
  }

  public InputCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public InputCompoundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.view_input_text, this, true);
  }
}
```

In fragment layout I use above custom view many times as per fields, like firstName, lastName and email. Views getting shown fine. But the issue is when I navigate to next fragment and come back to this fragment again, other two views values are getting replaced with email value.

**Note** - This issue is not related to **not to use of liveData**, FYI I also tried setting hard coded value on onViewCreated but even those values are getting replaced with email value.

FYI, whereas if I do not use the custom view instead just add view_input_text layout in fragment layout, seems working fine.